# What is the opposite of real-time?

Tags: phrase-request

In computer science there is the term *real-time*. Is there any word to say something is not real time? *Non-real time* doesn't sound good to me.

Comment: The answer might be [batch processing](http://www.ask.com/question/real-time-versus-batch-processing), but it depends on what you mean by "opposite".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lets take an example here: 
You login to your Facebook account and post a comment. How **Facebook updates this comment** to your Facebook wall and your friends wall & also the **time delay** will determine the update mode.
(although there are other parameters also).

**1. Real Time-** Comment is updated online and delay is less than 2 seconds.

**2. Near Real Time-** A delay of 2~10 seconds is expected, however, exact definition depends on SLA between the involved parties. Facebook works on near real time mode.

**3.  Offline Mode or Batch Processing-** The data is updated via files to the database, exact definition depends on SLA between the involved parties. In general time delay is in hours (in every ~6 to 12 hrs). Offline or batch processing is answer to your question.

Answer (score 6):

*Deferred* could definitely be used to denote what is *not real-time* in appropriate contexts.

For ex: *Deferred* is already used by Oracle as a part of a term *Deferred Processing* which is a feature that allows long-running tasks to be handled by background engines instead of in real time. [More here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/integrate.1012/b12163/wfapi04.htm).

Answer (score 3):

If it's not *real-time*, it's *non-real-time*.  Other terms may be useful to describe something which is non-real-time, but that is nonetheless the correct term.

Answer (score 2):

In computer science, *real-time* is used to describe a characteristic of reactive systems, those have a constraint on the delay between the event and the response to the event.  (It is often subdivided in *hard* --- when missing any deadline is a failure --- *firm* --- when missing some deadline is allowed at the cost of reducing the quality and missed responses are of no utility --- and *soft* --- when having a late response is better than having none).  I know of no word describing non-real-time systems in this sense.

*Batch* or *offline* systems are just systems which are working alone, as opposed to *online* systems which interact either with the world (the *reactive systems*) or users (the *interactive systems*).

As usual, definitions tend to vary a little depending on authors and their purpose (especially the division between interactive systems and soft real-time one is more one of intend, context and tradition than anything else).

Notes:

- *Real-time* is also used informally to describe interactive systems for which the interaction is quick enough that it doesn't suffer from the response time.  Non-real-time systems in this sense are just called *slow*.
- *Online/offline* is also used to describes systems needing or not needing a network connection.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking at "age" and "operability" of business data, you might consider "historical" vs. "real-time" data.

Answer (score 0):

These aren't exact antonyms, but I think they would work in certain contexts. My use case is: "*realtime games vs ___ games*".

You could emphasize the difference in length of time with: *extended, ongoing, or long-term*.

You could emphasize the broken quality of time with: *discontinuous, periodic, fragmented, or intermittent*.

Comment: If you're talking about games only, it would be [real-time versus **turn-based**](https://jonshaferondesign.com/2013/01/03/turn-based-vs-real-time/).

Answer (score -1):

Try to use "Near-Real time" as antonym for real time.

Comment: what about "offline"?

Comment: Hi, I think offline is also a good option, but, it is oftenly used as antonym for "Online".

Comment: Near real-time means its close to real-time, which is not exactly the opposite of real-time.